# Setting a Div containing a background image to width:100% and height:auto causing it to not display

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div called #rightside, and within this parent div I have 2 more divs, one a google map called #mapcanvas and the other a div called #buildingpic which contains a background image of our building. I am making the site using relative sizes, but for some reason, when I switch the size of the background image from absolute sizes in pixels to relative ones using percentages and auto, the #buildingpc disappears and the only thing displaying is the #mapcanvas.

heres the HTML for the #rightside parent and the 2 children div's.

```
<div id="rightside">
     <h1>Where To Find Us</h1>
   <a href="img/buildingpic.jpg"><div id="buildingpic"></div></a>
     <br>   
      <div id="map_canvas">
            <script>
                function initialize() {

                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.960478, -75.603013);
                    var mapOptions = {
                    center: myLatlng,
                    zoom: 19,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
                    },
                    zoomControl: true,
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                    },
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions, marker);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                     map: map
                    });
                 }

              google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
         </script>
     </div>
```

And CSS:

```
#rightside {
width: 20%;
padding: 1em 0px;
display: inline-block;
background: #FFFFFF;
margin: 10px 5px 8px 10px;
border: none;
}

#rightside h1 {
 width: 90%;
 margin: 8px auto ;
 background: #FF0000;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888;
 text-shadow: #CCC 1px 1px 1px;
 font-size: 1.35em; 
 padding: 10px 2%;
 color: #FFFFFF; 

 }

#buildingpic {
background-image: url(../img/buildingpicresize.jpg);
display: block;
width:  100%;
height: auto;
margin: 1em auto 0;
border-radius: 1px;
border: 1px 1px 1px 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.2);
 }

#location {
text-align: center;
color: #878787;
font-weight: bold;
}

#map_canvas { display: block; width: 300px; height: 300px;  padding: 0; margin:0 auto 0;  padding-bottom:15px; background-color: #CCC; 
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 1px 1px 1px 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.2);
}

/* overrides the css max-width 100% browser reset("normalizer") otherwise googlemaps zoom in/out buttons dont display properly*/
#map_canvas img {
max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`height: auto;` for a `div` is `0`.  Try adding `min-height: 1em;` to the offender.  If a sliver of it shows up, you'll know it was disappearing because there's nothing in the div.  If you need it to be a given aspect ratio—say, for example 2:1—do this:

```
.offender {
    height: 0;
    // no min-height
    padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

`padding` when set as a percentage references it's width.  `padding-bottom: 50%;`, therefore, means the element will always be 1/2 as tall as it is wide.

An even more foolproof version of this technique using a pseudo-element can be found here: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Comment: thanks, the image displays now. However when I resize the browser instead of the image shrinking in size relatively to the size of the browser, it slowly gets cut off

Comment: @user3376521 Try adding `background-size: contain;` or `background-size: cover;`

Comment: that was infinitely useful to me, thanks a lot for your help. with background-size: contain; and preserving the aspect ratio it is working perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without any contents `height: auto` will default to 0, a `min-height` or specific height will be needed...

You could always replaced the background div with the image itself, if you set it's `width: 100%; height: auto;` it'll scale vertically in relation to it's width. You could also wrap this in a div with a `max-height` if you wanted to limit the height.